# What to use for large numbers with precision?

Tags: android, variables

I need a way to store large numbers with precision. Let's say I want to have 1'234'567'890.123456 in a variable. I was thinking about using Strings ( though it's not recommended ) but I believe there must be a much better way to do this.

Comment: Something like BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) gives you numbers with arbitrary precision. It is serialisable so you could save it like that, or use toString() and save that representation.

Comment: Gonna take a look, thanks for answer : )
It seems `promising`, gonna try this in my code

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BigDecimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html). They are `Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.`

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering as well, though fractalwrench was faters :P